# bootstrap snippet searchbox not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I am using this snippet for my site: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/inline-navbar-search
  But it does not seem to work as intended.As you can see in the image, when I click the search icon, the whole search box goes to left over the brand logo.
I see that the snippet was made for bootstrap 3.1.0 How can I make it to work like in the snippet for bootstrap 3.3.7 ?

[image]

Comment: Show you HTML and CSS code for better understanding of issue.

Comment: Is the exact same code from that snippet.

Comment: Yes but, the css of your site and demo snippet may be conflicting. so without seeing the html and css code of you site nobody can trace the issue.

Comment: Also, if you can show the code using  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) then it will be very easy to solve.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/BYu22boGPn Here.This should be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with adding

```
text-align: right
```

in block like:

```
header .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #D04746 !important;
    z-index: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
```